# How to do or what is the name of this effect? (image in description)

Tags: css, reactjs, jsx

I need to do this feat. When it has more than 3 images, it will place a fourth image with the remaining number of images.
I am currently coding in reactjs.

[image]

Code:

```
<Speaker>
 {event.speakers.map((speakerItem) => {
  return <img src={speakerItem.photo} />
 })}
</Speaker>
```

styled using [styled-components](https://www.npmjs.com/package/styled-components)

```
export const Speaker = styled.div`
  margin-left: 10px;

  img {
    width: 44px;
    height: 44px;
    object-fit: cover;
    border-radius: 22px;
    border: 2px solid #fff;
    margin-left: -10px;
  }
`;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try something with this kind of code :

```
<Speaker>
 {event.speakers.map((speakerItem, index) => {
   if (index < 3) {
       return <img src={speakerItem.photo} />
   } else if (index === 3) {
      return <MyBubble count={speakerItem.length - 3} />
   }

 })}
</Speaker>
```

Where `MyBubble` is a custom component who render the remaining number...